# Why does expression in reused workflow "with" give "Unexpected value 'env'"?

Tags: github-actions

I'm making a GitHub Actions workflow that calls another workflow in a different repository.  I tried to use an environment variable inside an expression for one of the `with` keys I am passing to the called workflow, but I got this error:

> The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/sample.yml (Line: 6, Col:
> 5): Unexpected value 'env' .github/workflows/sample.yml (Line: 9, Col:
> 23): Unrecognized named-value: 'env'. Located at position 1 within
> expression: env.SOMETHING

```
on:
  push:
jobs:
  call-workflow-in-another-repository:
    uses: my-org/my-repo/.github/workflows/sample-workflow.yml@v1
    env:
      SOMETHING: example
    with:
      something-sent: ${{ env.SOMETHING }}
      something-else-sent: ${{ format('{0}_another_usage_of_env_variable', env.SOMETHING) }}
```

I read [in documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#env-context):

> You can use the env context in the value of any key in a step except
> for the `id` and `uses` keys

Why isn't this reference to env working here?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that my usage is not actually inside a **step** but is inside a **job** instead.  [Per documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#inputs-context) I could use  `inputs` in the expression because inputs can be accessed

> from any job or step in a workflow

But at the time of writing, using `env` isn't supported yet inside a `with` key of a reusable workflow call.